# Java How do I create a random number mod 5?

Tags: java, random

Java How do I create a random number mod 5 ?

I need only random numbers 0-100, divisible by 5

something like `RandomNumber.nextInt(100) % 5`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do this:

```
int randomMultipleOf5 = 5*random.nextInt(21);
```

21 is needed to get an integer in the range 0-20 (inclusive). When multiplied by 5 you get a number in the range 0-100 (inclusive).

Comment: Because `Random.nextInt(n)` returns a number between 0 inclusive and n exclusive, and you want something between `0` and `20` inclusive.

Comment: because `nextInt(n)` produces a number between `0` and `n-1`. In this case, we want `n-1 = 20` because `20 * 5 = 100`.

Answer (score 6):

You can just do:

```
Random r = new Random();
int randomMultipleOfFive = r.nextInt(21)*5; //generates a number between 0 and 20 inclusive then *5
```

Answer (score 5):

```
int random = new Random().nextInt(21) * 5
```

Answer (score 4):

How about;

```
int number = RandomNumber.nextInt(21) * 5;
```

To clarify, `nextInt(21)` generates a number from 0-20 making 100 a possible generated number, while `nextInt(20)` would only max generate 95.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Random random = new Random();

for(int i=0; i<50; ++i){
    System.out.println(random.nextInt(21) * 5);
}